# How to get data from property list into an NSArray programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I have generated a property list which save some hospital names. Now I want to get the names into an array from that plist. please help me. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"plist"];
contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

try this

Comment: You probably need to accept the answer if you get correct answer by clicking tick mark on the left side of the answer

Comment: AssamHospitals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                 pathForResource:@"HospitalListAssam" ofType:@"plist"]];

Comment: What was your question? please specify

Comment: I have used the above code snippet and it worked fine for me. Thanx a lot. Now I want to display the array in table view in from a specific table cell. I mean i want to leave blank cell number one. How to do that?????? please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to leave cell 1 blank?

Comment: To place blank cell you need to place if condition in
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}`
in this place if condition as `if(indexPath == 1){ cell = @"";return cell}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

NSError *error;
// Look in Documents for an existing plist file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* metadataPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Metadata.plist"]];
[metadataPlistPath retain];

// If it's not there, copy it from the bundle
NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ( ![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:metadataPlistPath] ) {
NSString *pathToSettingsInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"Metadata" ofType:@"plist"];
[fileManger copyItemAtPath:pathToSettingsInBundle toPath:metadataPlistPath error:&amp;error];
}
//Now read the plist file from Documents
NSString* myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Metadata.plist"] ];

dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPlistPath];

return dictionary;
}

//fetch the data based on key
- (NSMutableArray*) fetchMetadataArrayForKey:(NSString*)aKey {
NSMutableArray* arrCategories = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [self fetchMetadata];

arrCategories = [dictionary valueForKey:aKey];

return arrCategories;

}
```